# Bash Globbing Pattern Matching for Imagemagick recursive convert to pdf

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, imagemagick

I have the following 2 scripts, that recursively convert folders of images to pdf's for my wifes japanese manga kindle using find and Imagemagick convert:

```
#!/bin/bash
_d="$(pwd)"
echo "$_d"
find . -type d -exec echo "Will convert in the following order: {}" \;
find . -type d -exec echo "Converting: '{}'" \;  -exec convert '{}/*.jpg' "$_d/{}.pdf" \;
```

and the same for PNG

```
#!/bin/bash
_d="$(pwd)"
echo "$_d"
find . -type d -exec echo "Will convert in the following order: {}" \;
find . -type d -exec echo "Converting: '{}'" \;  -exec convert '{}/*.png' "$_d/{}.pdf" \;
```

Unfortunately I am not able make one universal script that works for all image formats.
How do I make one script that works for both ?
I would also need JPG,PNG as well as jpeg,JPEG

Thx in advance

Comment: `$_d/{}.pdf` could just be `{}.pdf`

Comment: @xcadme : what's wroing with your answer. The deleted version looks perfectly acceptable. Even if the O.P. wrote you a message asking for "one more thing", your work deserves credit (and it may provide OP with something to think about). Others may be able to extend your solution for other purposes. Well written and formatted, keep it posted! Good luck to all.

Comment: You didn't actually really say what you want to do... you want to recursively find all jpeg, JPEG, jpg, JPG, PNG, png files and make each one into a single PDF? And save it where?

Comment: You're also copying files to a single directory right? So you need to handle duplicate filenames. Unless `convert` does this for you?

Comment: @Mark Setchell, yes I want to recursively find all image files starting from a root folder, let's say /media/Backup/Mangas. In this folder I have quite many subfolders. I want to convert all the images in these subfolders, save the pdf's with the name of the image folder -> in the root folder, no matter how deep recursion goes.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `find` at all, just a loop:

```bash
#!/use/bin/env bash

# enable recursive globs
shopt -s globstar

for dir in **/*/; do
    printf "Converting jpgs in %s\n" "$dir"
    convert "$dir"/*.jpg "$dir/out.pdf"
done
```

If you want to combine .jpg and .JPG in the same pdf, add `nocaseglob` to the `shopt` line. Add .jpeg to the mix? Add `extglob` and change `"$dir"/*.jpg` to `"$dir"/*.@(jpg|jpeg)`

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

# enable recursive globs
shopt -s globstar nocaseglob extglob 

for dir in **/*/; do
    printf "Converting (jpg|jpeg|png) in %s\n" "$dir"
    convert "$dir"/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png) "$dir/out.pdf"
done`
@Shawn This works, but it saves all pdfs in the image directory with the name out.pdf, I really want them named properly in the caller directory. Thx for the answer anyway.

Comment: I couldn't figure out where or how you wanted the PDFs named so I made something up. Easy to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do more complicated actions if you turn the find exec into a bash function (or even a standalone script).

```
#!/bin/bash

do_convert()(
    shopt -s nullglob
    for dir in "$@"; do
        files=("$dir"/*.{jpg,JPG,PNG,jpeg,JPEG})
        if [[ -z $files ]]; then
            echo 1>&2 "no suitable files in $dir"
            continue
        fi
        echo "Converting $dir"
        convert "${files[@]}" "$dir.pdf"
    done
)
export -f do_convert

pwd

echo "Will convert in the following order:"
find . -type d

# find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert {}' \;
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert "$@"' -- {} \+
```

- `nullglob` makes `*.xyz` return nothing if there is no match, instead of returning the original string unchanged
- `p/*.{a,b,c}` expands into `p/*.a` `p/*.b` `p/*.c` before the `*` are expanded
- `x()(...)` instead of the more normal `x(){...}` uses a subshell so we don't have to remember to unset `nullglob` again or clean up any variable definitions
- `export -f x` makes function `x` available in subshells
- we skip conversion if there are no suitable files
- with the slightly more complicated find command, we can reduce the number of invocations of `bash` (probably doesn't save a great deal in this particular case)

Comment: This works out of the box ! Thanks a lot ! 
`#!/bin/bash

do_convert()(
    shopt -s nullglob
    for dir in "$@"; do
        files=("$dir"/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,jpeg,JPEG})
        if [[ -z $files ]]; then
            echo 1>&2 "no suitable files in $dir"
            continue
        fi
        echo "Converting $dir"
        convert "${files[@]}" "$dir.pdf"
    done
)
export -f do_convert

pwd

echo "Will convert in the following order:"
find . -type d

# find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert {}' \;
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert "$@"' -- {} \+ `

Comment: `find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert "$@"' -- {} \+ ` <-could you elaborate on the function call ?

Comment: `bash -c cmdline comment args` : `'do_convert "$@"'` is cmdline (single-quoted to protect space and prevent variable expansion); `--` is comment; `{} \+` becomes args (added by find - see `-exec` syntax`)

Comment: if you put do_convert in a separate bash script (ie. the `...` of `do_convert()(...)`), then you can just use `find ... -exec do_convert.sh {} \+`

Answer (score 1):

how about a one-liner

#### dry-run

```
find -name \*.jpg -or -name \*.png | xargs -I xxx echo  "xxx =>" xxx.pdf
```

#### run

```bash
find -name \*.jpg -or -name \*.png | xargs -I xxx echo xxx xxx.pdf
```

help

- `-name` match name
- `-or` logical or => both jpg and png
- `xargs` map input into a name to execute a command on
- `-I` select a name, it is like `{}` in file

---

NOTE

- instead of `$(pwd)` which is a command substitution you can use variable `$PWD`
- `xxx` maps into a name and `xxx.pdf` still has the matched extension found by `find`. which means `filename.png` becomes `filename.png.pdf`. If this is not desired, you can `sed` it
- to run `convert` command in **parallel** you can use `-P 0` with `xargs` -- see `xargs --help`

With `sed` to remove extensions

#### dry-run

```bash
find -name \*.jpg -or -name \*.png | sed 's/.\(png\|jpg\)$//g' | xargs -I xxx echo "xxx =>" xxx.pdf
```

Comment: this puts one image per pdf but the question seems to ask for one directory of images per pdf. @Tobi will have to confirm desired spec

Comment: @jhnc thanks - yes , you are right, he can update `find` to match just **directories**. I demonstrated the pattern, not all the use case of `find` and `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

@shawn Your solution works, just as I stated in the comments, I am to stupid to name the resulting pdf properly (folder name) and save in the script caller directory. Nevertheless, it solves my case insensitive jpg, jpeg, png problems just fine.
Here is shawns solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# enable recursive globs
shopt -s globstar nocaseglob extglob 

for dir in **/*/; do
    printf "Converting (jpg|jpeg|png) in %s\n" "$dir"
    convert "$dir"/*.@(jpg|jpeg|png) "$dir/out.pdf"
done
```

@jhnc Your solution works out of the box, it does exactly what I intended, and I really like calling functions, or even standalone scripts to increase complexity. One drawback is, that I can not Ctrl-c the process, because it is thereby threaded, or runs in a subshell ? I think you were missing an exit statement at the end of the function, it never stopped.

```
#!/bin/bash

do_convert()(
    shopt -s nullglob
    for dir in "$@"; do
        files=("$dir"/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,jpeg,JPEG})
        if [[ -z $files ]]; then
            echo 1>&2 "no suitable files in $dir"
            continue
        fi
        echo "Converting $dir"
        convert "${files[@]}" "$dir.pdf"
    done
    exit
)
export -f do_convert

pwd

echo "Will convert in the following order:"
find . -type d

# find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert {}' \;
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'do_convert "$@"' -- {} \+
```

@ everyone else, it's already after midnight again, I guess this is a trivial question for you guys, and I am very grateful for your ALL your answers, I didn't have the time to try everything.

I find linux bash very challenging.

Comment: P.S: I am unable to upvote any comment since I have less than 15 reputation.

Answer (score -2):

A lot of ways to skin this cat. My thought is:

```
for F in `find . -type f -print`
do
  TYPE=`file -n --mime-type $F`
  if [ "$TYPE" = image/png ]
  then
     ## do png conversion here
  elif [ "$TYPE" = image/jpg ]
  then
     ## do jpg conversion here
  fi
done
```

Comment: this breaks if filenames contain whitespace